# How to manage $50k in Savings?

Tags: united-states

I have around $50k in savings that I would like to be able to use without penalties. The money is already in a 1% interest money market fund. How can I invest a portion of the money without a ton of risk? My wife and I are in our early 40s and have a combined $200k+ in our 401k accts. Thanks.

Comment: Without more information, this is a very broad question. What is "a ton of risk" to you? What are your financial goals? What are you able to contribute on an ongoing basis to meet those goals? etc.

Comment: What do you mean "without penalties?"  Where is the money now, is it in an IRA or some other vehicle that could incur a withdrawal penalty?

Answer (score 2):

In today's market being paid 1% for risk and free access money is pretty darn good.  If 50k is what you feel comfortable with an emergency fund, then you are doing a fine enough job.

To me that is a lot to keep in an emergency fund, however several factors play into this:

- My kids are grown
- My wife and I both work, and are our pay is close to equal.
- Both of our jobs are pretty secure
- My expenses are very low.  (I could probably make 50K last 18 months with no other income.)

We both drive older cars, so I also keep enough money around to replace one of them.

Considering all that I keep a specific amount in savings that for me earns .89%.  Some of that is kept in our checking accounts which earns nothing.

You have to go through some analysis of your own situation and keep that amount where it is.

If that amount is less than 50K, you have some money to play with.  Here are some options:

- Laddering CDs - earns a bit more, still very little risk
- Bonds
- Preferred Stock (like bonds)
- Dividend paying investments (dividends tend to stabilize prices)
- Index funds (Tends to be a low turnover of investments minimizing tax events)

Comment: Laddered CDs have the obvious risk of **insufficient liquidity.** Just because the risk of losing your money is small doesn't mean there is no risk; in that case, it just takes on a different form.